# Android Schedule SMS

Tags: java, android, xml, sms

How to schedule the sms that i have already brought it to outbox from database(SQLite database). I have listed the messages that have been sent to outbox. How to schedule the time for the message in outbox? When i set the time, the message must goto outbox and wait for the particular time to be reached. When the time reaches, the message should be sent. I have already coded for messaging , database storing, retrieving to list view to outbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CountDownTimer Constructor` to make time based event to happen.